# How to manipulate SVG background image with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, css, svg

I want to remove the `viewBox` property of the root `svg` element in a background image with JavaScript. How would I do that?

```css
.box {
  background-image: url(http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/8/86/CC-logo.svg);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: auto auto;
  width: 300px;
  height: 150px;
  border: 1px solid;
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
  stretch background
</div>
```

Here are the first few characters from the SVG file.

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="100%" height="100%" viewBox="0 0 512 123">
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use an [SVG fragment identifier](http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/linking.html#SVGFragmentIdentifiers) together with viewBox(none)

Change the URL to

```
http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/8/86/CC-logo.svg#svgView(viewBox(none))
```

This will work in Firefox (and did work in Opera 12). Not sure how many other UAs support viewBox(none) from [SVG 1.2 tiny](http://www.w3.org/TR/SVGTiny12/coords.html#ViewBoxAttribute) though.

Answer (score 1):

Answer to my own question. I'm not going to accept it. Just for demonstration purposes. This snippet tested in Chrome and Firefox. Works only in Firefox. It uses CSS property animation, CSS transition and SVG fragment identifier animation all in one.

```js
    function SVGBackground(elm, url) {
        this.elm = elm;
        this.url = url;

        this.stretch = function() {
            this.elm.style.backgroundImage = 'url(\'' + this.url + '#svgView(preserveAspectRatio(none))' + '\')';
        }
        this.setViewBox = function(minx, miny, width, height) {
            this.elm.style.backgroundImage = 'url(\'' + this.url + '#svgView(preserveAspectRatio(none);viewBox('
                + minx + ',' + miny + ',' + width + ',' + height + '))' + '\')';
        }
    }
    window.onload = function() {
        var box = document.querySelector('.box');

        var svgBg = new SVGBackground(box, 'http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/8/86/CC-logo.svg');
        svgBg.stretch();
        var w = 0, h = 0;
        var aspect = 512 / 123;
        var interval = setInterval(function() {
            if(w > 512) {
                clearInterval(interval);
                svgBg.stretch();
                $(box).css('background-size', '100% 100%');
                $(box).animate({
                    "opacity": '1',
                }, 400);
                return;
            }
            w+=5;h+=5 / aspect;
            svgBg.setViewBox(0,0,w,h);
        }, 1000 / 60);

    }
```

```css
.box {
  width: 500px;
  height: 123px;
  background-size: 20% 50%;
  transition: background-size 0.4s;
  opacity: 0.5;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.4.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="box"></div>
    </body>
</html>
```